# Desmos plot only for integral $x$

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I'm trying to plot $2\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{2}x\right)+1$ but only if $x$ is a natural number.
Desmos plots correctly
$2\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{2}x\right)+1$
[image]

I would like this however:

[image]

I achieved this using a list of points $[(1,1),(2,3),(3,3),(4,5)\ldots]$ but I would like to plot up to infinity and I don't think desmos supports list comprehensions like that.

So instead I tried using desmos-style piecewise functions like $y=\left\{\operatorname{mod}\left(x,1\right)=0:2\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{2}x\right)+1\right\}$ but this has no output at all.

So, how can I create a graphic like the second for all natural $x$? (At least up to $x=2^{2700}$)

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya if you yourself have tried that, you would know that it does not satisfy what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/trvx3p6xo4) will get you what you want.

[image]

The idea is to define a function, then plot points using a list.

In this case, we define a function $$f(x)=2\text{floor}(\log_2x)+1$$ and make the calculator plot points $(a,f(a))$ where $a\in(1,2,3,...)$.

Comment: How do I use the list of natural numbers for $a$?

Comment: Define it explicitly as a list in one of the fields available.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks for the answer I was also trying to find a solution found one but it was only limited to 100 numbers. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd like to go up to at least 2^2700

Comment: upvoted both the ques and ans